# How to handle free text in a custom Alexa skill?

Tags: java, node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

for learning purposes, I want to create an AWS Lambda function which is called by a custom Alexa skill. The purpose of this function is to send a message (email,SMS) to a specified recipient.
I know how to create functions and everything works fine except the part where the user of Alexa provides her a free text she should send. I know the concept of Slots, but there I can only define fix values. Is there a way to receive free text and use it in the Lambda function (Java or Node.js)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It used to be possible to capture "free" text using the AMAZON.LITERAL slot type but that has been deprecated and there is no easy workaround yet.

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interaction-model-reference#literal-slot-type-reference

Answer (score 1):

searchQuery slot type for a custom intent is the alternative for Amazon.literal.

I was able to receive it successfully in node js.

```
  // The handlers object tells Alexa how to handle various actions
  var handlers = {
  "createtask": function () 
  {
    console.log(this.event.request.intent.slots.taskName.value);//Free Text.
  }
```

[Link](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/a2716002-0f50-4587-b038-31ce631c0c07/enhance-speech-recognition-of-your-alexa-skills-with-phrase-slots-and-amazon-searchquery)